# SQL select record right after a particular date, compare NULL with date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I like to keep all records in tableA that are right after my targeted date,

Main table A

[image]

Table B

[image]

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA a
LEFT JOIN tableB b on b.customerID  = a.customerID and b.target_date = a.sell_date
WHERE a.sell_date > b.target_date
```

Unfortunately my code above doesn't work since SQL can't compare NULL with date.

My expected output is

[image]

Comment: There is no null in your sample data, so where is this null/date compare happening?

Comment: Just remove the date condition from the join clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality between target_date and sell_date could go in the join condition of the FROM clause.  This way the WHERE clause could be eliminated.

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA a
     LEFT JOIN tableB b on b.customerID=a.customerID
                           and b.target_date <= a.sell_date;
```

Comment: you need to remove the LEFT word, to get the expected output, anyway, answer help